# Scope of Static Members in PHP and Concurrency

Tags: php, concurrency, static, scope, member

I have a class that is declared in my application that has a private static member like so:

```
class SomeClass{
private static myMember =  array(); 

public static getterFunction(){}
public static setterFunction(){}

}
```

My question / concern is that multiple requests (i'm thinking like a thread in Java) would be able to modify this static member.  My understanding of php scope and static members is that they are in the request scope and a new variable is created for each new request and subsequently destroyed after the request has been fulfilled.  That said, this would be a difficult thing to test (at least i can't think of an easy way) so i'd rather be safe than sorry.

Is my assessment correct?  The PHP docs i've read are pretty crappy in terms of detail so I haven't been able to authoritatively answer yet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No data, *none*, is persistent or shared across different instances of PHP scripts unless you explicitly make it so (for example using sessions, databases, files, shared memory). Each PHP instance is its own thing, and each new request causes the webserver to start a separate instance.

So yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks man.  I appreciate having more eyeballs than mine on this.

Comment: @deceze Where did you get that information from? Not that I would doubt it, but the PHP docs are often very unspecific and it's hard to get authoritative information on details.

Comment: @Elmar I couldn't even tell you that. It's so elemental to the way PHP works, I don't know how explicit this is actually mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have shared memory by default in PHP. Every single request is being processed in separate process, so they do not know about each other.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

For example:

You have a simple script.php file that sets private field in a class when GET parameter passed:

```
<?
class A {
  private $x = 1;
  public function setX($x) {$this->x = $x;}
  public function getX() {return $this->x;}
}

$a = new A();
if (!empty($_GET['x'])) {
  $a->setX($_GET['x']);
  sleep(3);
}

echo $a->getX();
?>
```

You do two requests at once:

```
GET /script.php?x=5
GET /script.php
```

Second request will print you "1". Yes, you are correct!